# Is it safe to initialize db references outside of a cloud function definition?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've written the following as a hello-world sort of "my first cloud function":

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.database();
const messagesRef = db.ref('/messages/general');

export const sendMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const writeResult = await messagesRef.push(data.text)

  return {
    result: writeResult
  };
});
```

Note that admin, db, and messagesRef are all being declared outside of the function definition, in the interests of not having to do it every time.

Does this approach work? Are there any problems with doing it this way? For instance, if the db connection is lost somehow (perhaps by an outage), will this get restarted and safely reconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All a `DatabaseReference` does is point to a location in the database, so no interaction with the database happens at that point. Since the `messageRef` has no dependency on any data that is passed into `sendMessage`, it can safely be initialized in the global scope.

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer. Just want to say in passing I have read dozens of your firebase answers here on SO and they're really helping me a lot with my project. Thank you for taking the time to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works perfectly. Your db object is imported from the SDK without any dependency on variables from within the function, so it is fine.